# How do I get the req.files.path when uploading multiple images with Multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I would like to get an array of strings and each string is the path of where I have saved the image, all images are being save to a folder.

```
router.post("/", upload.array("songImage"), (req, res, next) => {
    // console.log(req.files[0].originalname);
    var file = req.files;
    console.log(file.path) // THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO GET THE ARRAY OF FILE PATHS
    const song = new Song({
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      name: req.body.name,
      composer: req.body.composer,
      productImage: req.files.path
    });
```

When I run this  get 'undefined'.

Thanks

Comment: `var paths = req.files.map(file => file.path)`

Comment: MadWard you are a god!!! Thanks so much it worked, pleas epost your answer as a solution so I can mark it as corect.

Comment: Sure, done. Didn't want to spam so I added a little explanation with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**

```
var paths = req.files.map(file => file.path)
```

**Slightly longer answer**

`req.files` is an array of objects (files), so you have to use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array that contains only the path of each file.

Answer (score 0):

also you can use this method

```
var path = req.files.objName[0].path
```

the number 0 differs based on which object you want to access